How to install a script with specific user(not root user) in do_instal function Yacto bb file?
Hi I am trying to install a script in a yacto project.
In a bb file, under do_install function like below
      install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/my_script.sh ${D}/${datadir}/

But it installing the script as root user. I have another user in my project as user1. user1 only going to use this script. I wants to install this script as user1.
Can anyone help me to do this?
I am expecting how example function to add specific user while installing this script.

In order to do this, you may need to add an user to system.
In recipe:

inherit useradd bbclass
mention for which package the user/group is required using USERADD_PACKAGES
mention commands to pass for useradd command to create user in USERADD_PARAM
same for GROUPADD_PARAM
if you wish to modify the group members you may use GROUPMEMS_PARAM
now in do_install section first install the files and then modify their user/group

There's a clear documentation and recipe example on how to add the new user and install files for that user.
please find the links here:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-useradd
https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb
Additional info:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-extrausers
